# Can't understand the line of code of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am a beginner and learning flask. While doing an exercise, I can't understand some code. Can anyone explain me the line with for loop?

```
@app.route("/details/<int:pet_id>")
def pet_details(pet_id):
    pet = next((pet for pet in pets if pet["id"] == pet_id), None) 
    if pet is None: 
        abort(404, description="No Pet was Found with the given ID")
    return render_template("details.html", pet = pet)
```

I can't understand this line from code

```
    pet = next((pet for pet in pets if pet["id"] == pet_id), None)
```

Comment: That line is a really complicated way of saying "get the pet with this id".

Comment: @JacobIRR ... I dont think pets is a dictionary... its a list of dictionaries ... also what would you expect pets.get('id') to be ... i assume he is trying to get a specific pet with a specific id

Comment: Another pyrrhic victory for one-liners?

Comment: This might be informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496536/how-do-python-set-comprehensions-work/20497109#20497109

Comment: @JacobIRR. next requires an iterator object. If in your scenario `pets.get('id')` is not an iterator, next would break it. Much easier to do `pets.get('id', None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` gets the next item from a generator, which in this case is `(pet for pet in pets if pet["id"] == pet_id)`. This generator will reduce your list/collection of `pet` objects to only those whose id is the same as the requested `pet_id`.

The `None` here is defaulting: if the generator has no next element, it'll typically throw a `StopIteration` exception, but in this case, `next` will handle the exception and instead return a `None` object instead of throwing an error